# Get active-slide with Angular from Ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this:

```
<ion-slide-box>
<ion-slide id="0">  
<div class="box"><img src="img/alfa.png" alt="Alfa" h"><h1>Alfa<h1></div>               
</ion-slide>  
<ion-slide  id="1">
<div class="box"><img src="img/dado_1_2.png" alt="1/2 Dado"    
</ion-slide-box>
```

Etc.

And on a button I'm trying to call a function. In that function in app.js I'm trying to get the active ion-slide but I'm not sure how. I succesfully fire the function, but there I'm not sure how to get the $INDEX from the active ion-slide.

Answer (score 1):

$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex() solved the problem. Thank you. Don't forget to inject it if anyone faces the same problem.